# Unreal Development Kit equivalent for Mac?

Tags: unreal-development-kit

I wanted to start learning/using UDK but its not mac compatible...

Can anyone suggest other engines that are similar to UDK (2d is good too) and run on a mac.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably [Unity3d](http://unity3d.com) is what you are looking for.

Comment: and they have a free version! Awesome!

Comment: Unity actually came from Mac :P UDK that is the "unity equivalent" for windows.

Comment: Late comment, but whatever. Unity development began in 2001 and was released in 2005. Unreal Engine 1 made its debut in 1998 and Unreal Engine 2 in 2002. Free version of Unreal Engine 3 (UDK) was released in 2009. Sources: http://unity3d.com/company/fast-facts http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unreal_Engine